# JQuery mobile multiple select menu display items?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile, menu

I have a select multiple menu in Jquery Mobile 1.1.  I know the default behavior is to show the item(s) selected and the number once you select items(s) and close the menu.

My question is that I would rather always display the first item and the number NOT the selected items. For example, if I have a menu:

```
<select name="color-choice" id="color-choice" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
   <option>Color Choices</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

And the user chooses red and green, I want the close menu to read "Color Choices (2)" instead of the default "Red, Blue (2)".

This is to save space, as I have a few menus and would like to dispense with labels, and have the user tell at a glance that a menu is "color choices" and that they have choses 2.

Possible?

Comment: There is no option for this, but hacking this into JQM shouldn't be hard. Check the selectmenu plugin, see how plugin options are defined, set your own option (best data-attributable) and in build function, find the text display. instead of displaying the text, check for your new option. if option is defined, use it, otherwise  default JQM.

Comment: @Steve, I know this is old, but I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.  Have there been any changes that would allow this, or does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a function that will save the selected item when the option is selected, then reset to the default option.

```
<select name="color-choice" id="color-choice" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">Color Choices</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<div>
    <input style="display:none;" id="hidden-choice" name="hidden-choice" value="" />        
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#color-choice').change (function (e) { 
            hidden-choice.value = document.getElementById('color- choice').value;
            color-choice.value = "";
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.